# Laravel checkbox value

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in Laravel and I'm trying to get values from a checkbox. 
I'm trying to receive `regeneration_id` which is needed to create a report however, the value is always `null`.

**View:**

```
     @foreach ($regenerations as $regeneration)
                            @if ($regeneration -> invoice_id == NULL)

                            <tr>

                                <td>{{ $regeneration -> id }}</td>
                                <td>                  
                                  @if ($regeneration -> source == 1) Praca: {{ $regeneration -> source_id }}  
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> source == 2) Sprzedaż: {{ $regeneration -> source_id }}
                                  @else Nieznane
                                  @endif </td>
                                <td>{{ $regeneration -> product_name }}</td>
                                <td>
                                  @if ($regeneration -> difficulty == 0) Nie ustalono
                                  @else {{ $regeneration -> difficulty }}
                                  @endif
                                </td>
                                <td>{{ $regeneration -> date_expected }}</td>

{{-- showing status of each regeneration --}}                              
                                <td>
                                  @if     ($regeneration -> status == 0 && $regeneration -> state == 2) <font color="red">Salon nie ocenione</font>
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 0 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Salon ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 1 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Wysłane MC ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 2 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Odebrane MC ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 3 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Wysłane SP ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 4 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Odebrane SP ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 4 && $regeneration -> state == 4) Odebrane SP niezregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 4 && $regeneration -> state == 5) Odebrane SP zregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 1 && $regeneration -> state == 4) Wysłane MC niezregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 1 && $regeneration -> state == 5) Wysłane MC zregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 2 && $regeneration -> state == 4) Odebrane MC niezregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 2 && $regeneration -> state == 5) Odebrane MC zregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 0 && $regeneration -> state == 6) Salon wstrzymane
                                  @endif 
                                </td>
                                <td>{{$regeneration -> wholesale_price}} zł</td>
{{-- checkbox to add regeneration to an invoice --}}





                             <td>     
                                <a href="{{ url ('actual',  $regeneration -> id ) }}">Szczegóły</a>
                             </td>
<form method="POST" action = "{{ action ('RegenerationsInvoicesController@generate')}}">
    {{csrf_field()}} 
                             <td>
                                  <div class="form-check">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="regeneration[]" value = {{ $regeneration-> id }} ></input>
                                  </div>
                             </td> 
                             @endif 
                             @endforeach


                         </tr>

                      </table> 
               <button style="float: right;" type="submit" class= "btn btn-outline-success">Rozlicz</button>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function generate (Request $req)
{
   $regeneration_id = Input::get('regeneration');
   var_dump($regeneration_id);
}
```

What I'm trying is to get the input from checkbox but it always fails. 
Is that because my form starts outside of @foreach? Please help.

**Route:**

```
Route::post('/generateinvoice',RegenerationsInvoicesController@generate');
```

Comment: Can you move the input inside the form tag.

Comment: I tried but then my button doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

here try this

```
public function generate (Request $req)
{
         $regeneration_id = $req->input('regeneration');
         var_dump($regeneration_id);
}
```

---

edited change view

```
    @foreach ($regenerations as $regeneration)
                            @if ($regeneration -> invoice_id == NULL)

                            <tr>

                                <td>{{ $regeneration -> id }}</td>
                                <td>                  
                                  @if ($regeneration -> source == 1) Praca: {{ $regeneration -> source_id }}  
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> source == 2) Sprzedaż: {{ $regeneration -> source_id }}
                                  @else Nieznane
                                  @endif </td>
                                <td>{{ $regeneration -> product_name }}</td>
                                <td>
                                  @if ($regeneration -> difficulty == 0) Nie ustalono
                                  @else {{ $regeneration -> difficulty }}
                                  @endif
                                </td>
                                <td>{{ $regeneration -> date_expected }}</td>

{{-- showing status of each regeneration --}}                              
                                <td>
                                  @if     ($regeneration -> status == 0 && $regeneration -> state == 2) <font color="red">Salon nie ocenione</font>
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 0 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Salon ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 1 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Wysłane MC ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 2 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Odebrane MC ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 3 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Wysłane SP ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 4 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Odebrane SP ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 4 && $regeneration -> state == 4) Odebrane SP niezregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 4 && $regeneration -> state == 5) Odebrane SP zregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 1 && $regeneration -> state == 4) Wysłane MC niezregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 1 && $regeneration -> state == 5) Wysłane MC zregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 2 && $regeneration -> state == 4) Odebrane MC niezregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 2 && $regeneration -> state == 5) Odebrane MC zregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 0 && $regeneration -> state == 6) Salon wstrzymane
                                  @endif 
                                </td>
                                <td>{{$regeneration -> wholesale_price}} zł</td>
{{-- checkbox to add regeneration to an invoice --}}





                             <td>     
                                <a href="{{ url ('actual',  $regeneration -> id ) }}">Szczegóły</a>
                             </td>
                             @endif 
                             @endforeach
<form method="POST" action = "{{ action ('RegenerationsInvoicesController@generate')}}">
    {{csrf_field()}} 
    @foreach ($regenerations as $regeneration)
                            @if ($regeneration -> invoice_id == NULL)
                             <td>
                                  <div class="form-check">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="regeneration[]" value = {{ $regeneration-> id }} ></input>
                                  </div>
                             </td> 
                             @endif 
                             @endforeach


                         </tr>

                      </table> 
               <button style="float: right;" type="submit" class= "btn btn-outline-success">Rozlicz</button>
</form>
```

Comment: var_dump($regeneration_id); give still NULL :/

Comment: I'm afraid it's caused by foreach loop

Comment: @Kusy you should try `dd($req)` and see whats in $req

Comment: only token there

Comment: @Kusy why dont remove that 2 bracket in front regeneration'n input name?

Comment: I've removed them but didn't help :S

Comment: @Kusy  if ($regeneration -> invoice_id == NULL) What this is for?

Comment: I want to make method for not invoiced regeneration = kind of work. With my button I want to select with checkbox regenerations to be invoiced and create invoice and update invoice_id in regenerations table, later on it will not show these in my generate invoice view

Comment: @Kusy did you try `<input type="checkbox" name="regeneration" value = {{ $regeneration-> id }} ></input>`?

Comment: yes, the problem stays the same. What I tried is to put endforeach and endif after the button, which of course generates 3 buttons, but then I am able to grab regeneration_id, uhhh will dive in it again today fresh mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for effort given with this challange. I finally found what is wrong.
problem was only with view. I've placed my form in too far away, it should be in beginning of my table. The correct view should look like this, and it works perfectly.

```
     <form method="POST" action = "{{ action ('RegenerationsInvoicesController@generate')}}">
  {{csrf_field()}} 

                     <table style="width:100%">

                            <tr>
                                <th>ID </th>
                                <th>Źródło</th>
                                <th>Produkt</th>
                                <th>Stopień trudności</th>
                                <th>Spodziewana data</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Cena</th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Rozlicz</th>
                            </tr>



                            @foreach ($regenerations as $regeneration)
                            @if ($regeneration -> invoice_id == NULL)

                            <tr>

                                <td>{{ $regeneration -> id }}</td>
                                <td>                  
                                  @if ($regeneration -> source == 1) Praca: {{ $regeneration -> source_id }}  
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> source == 2) Sprzedaż: {{ $regeneration -> source_id }}
                                  @else Nieznane
                                  @endif </td>
                                <td>{{ $regeneration -> product_name }}</td>
                                <td>
                                  @if ($regeneration -> difficulty == 0) Nie ustalono
                                  @else {{ $regeneration -> difficulty }}
                                  @endif
                                </td>
                                <td>{{ $regeneration -> date_expected }}</td>

{{-- Wyświetlanie statusu złożonego z state i status --}}                              
                                <td>
                                  @if     ($regeneration -> status == 0 && $regeneration -> state == 2) <font color="red">Salon nie ocenione</font>
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 0 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Salon ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 1 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Wysłane MC ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 2 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Odebrane MC ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 3 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Wysłane SP ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 4 && $regeneration -> state == 3) Odebrane SP ocenione
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 4 && $regeneration -> state == 4) Odebrane SP niezregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 4 && $regeneration -> state == 5) Odebrane SP zregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 1 && $regeneration -> state == 4) Wysłane MC niezregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 1 && $regeneration -> state == 5) Wysłane MC zregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 2 && $regeneration -> state == 4) Odebrane MC niezregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 2 && $regeneration -> state == 5) Odebrane MC zregenerowane
                                  @elseif ($regeneration -> status == 0 && $regeneration -> state == 6) Salon wstrzymane
                                  @endif 
                                </td>
                                <td>{{$regeneration -> wholesale_price}} zł</td>
{{-- checkbox do dodania do rozliczenia --}}





                             <td>     
                                <a href="{{ url ('actual',  $regeneration -> id ) }}">Szczegóły</a>
                             </td>


                             <td>



                                  <div class="form-check">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="regeneration[]" value = "{{ $regeneration -> id }}" ></input>
                                  </div>
                             </td> 

                             @endif 
                             @endforeach

                         </tr>
                      </table>   
                <button style="float: right;" type="submit" class= "btn btn-outline-success">Rozlicz</button>
</form>
```